# Using ImageView control creating error in Android 

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am creating an application in android. And when I try running the app after inserting an ImageView control into my app, I am getting the following error in logCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   
ComponentInfo{com.bdisys.android.wsaccess/com.bdisys.boinfoportal.ui.FirstAppUI}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
```

The following came like a warning after I had inserted an ImageView into my layout/main.xml.

```
The following classes could not be found:
- ImageView (Change to android.widget.ImageView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

Following the xml code portion after I had inserted the ImageView.

```
<TableRow  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/favicon" />

    </TableRow>
```

Can anyone tell why this error comes?

Am not getting any idea about this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are triying to cast a `TextView` into `ImageView`. Check your resource xml.

Comment: no..am not trying for any casting..i just insert an imageView and try to run the app

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the `ImageView`, the message `The following classes...` was showing up in the design tab of my `main.xml`

In my case the problem was that the drawable had no extension, however it appeared in `@drawable/` section and was appearing in the autocomplete too as if nothing was wrong.

Cannot provide any info on the classcast exception though.

**To sum up: Make sure your favicon file has the correct extension**

Comment: similarly, something I thought was a PNG was actually a PSD file!

Answer (score 0):

if you have code like this

```
ImageView img;
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
```

change to

```
TextView txt;
txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
```